# Detect browser with the use of UserAgent

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, browser

I want to check if the active browser is Chrome, in TypeScript/JavaScript.

Earlier i have used

```
var isChrome = !!(<any>window).chrome && !!(<any>window).chrome.webstore;
```

But that doesn't seem to work anymore. What is the new approach? I do not wish to use UserAgent, due bad experience.

Comment: What is your use case? Most probably you want feature detection, not browser sniffing. Also please search and try the many other questions about this exact topic. You might want to have a look at the source code of https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769),
And code should look like:

```js
// Chrome 1 - 71
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
```

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: Thank you very much Oliver.

Comment: You are welcome :) btw if you want detect more browsers its on link in answer :)

Comment: as with Chrome 93, this seems to work only for HTTPS sites, as neither `window.chrome.webstore` now `window.chrome.runtime` is exposed on HTTP sites (not even on `localhost`)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the bowser library for this:

```js
console.log("You are using " + bowser.name + " version: " + bowser.version + " os: " + bowser.osname);

// Check for Chrome 20+
const isChrome = bowser.check({chrome: "20"}, true);
console.log("Chrome: ", isChrome);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/1.9.4/bowser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bowser still uses UserAgent if you look through its documentation

Comment: Thanks @RasmusPedersen, you're right about that. I think it gives you some nice features in addition!

Answer (score 1):

try to use the navigator global variable : `const isChrome = /chrome/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );`